# How to initialize a 2D vector inside a structure?

Tags: c++

I need a structure that contains a 2D vector.Something as follows

```
struct state
{
    vector<vector<int> > p(3,vector<int>(3));
};
state *puzzle;
```

But I get the following error :

> 9 25  C:\Users\Nikita\Documents\AI_8square_heuristic1.cpp [Error] expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Can someone please tell me how to initialize vector ? 
 Thank You.

Comment: you need `;` after class declaration

Comment: I apologize for that ....but that isn't exactly the problem..I still get the error

Comment: you can try `vector<vector<int> > p{3,vector<int>(3)};`

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: [it works here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0tEOYKFVRtrBeKXr).

Comment: It has to. What compiler and version?

Comment: Ohh..I am using Dev c++ but i guess it works only with c++11 .
Okie I'll update and try .Thank you !

Comment: @Kiera.K Dev C++ is not a compiler.  It is an integrated development environment.  The compiler it uses is more than likely an old version of `gcc`.

Comment: How are you allocating for `puzzle`? You declare a pointer instead of an instance, so you will need to use `new`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please tell me how I can check the version..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well I thought initializing it in 2 for loops would do it... Because the code works when p is an int array...I get the error only when I use vectors

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin
 for(...)
{for(...)
{ cin>> puzzle->p[i][j];
}
}
This works when p is a 2D int array...but not when its a 2D vector

Comment: @Kiera.K -- Why not simply create a default constructor and initialize the vector in the member initialization list?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I could do that too ! Thank you !
But I still don't get why this doesn't work..If it works for a 2D int array why not a 2D vector ?

Comment: @Kiera.K The member initialization list works with any "old" C++ 98 version compiler and above.  As a matter of fact that was the only way to accomplish this type of initialization for C++ 98, but it works and still works now with more modern compilers.  So there is no need to go to a C++11 compiler to accomplish your goal.  Also, you never showed the 2D array syntax you claim is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initialization can also work simply by replacing your *parenthesis* with *braces*, for example:

```
struct state
{
    vector<vector<int>> p{3,vector<int>(3)};
};
```

is fine.

Now how you are using it may be a problem. Initially you show declaring a pointer to `state`, e.g. `state *puzzle;` However that would require that you allocate storage for an instance. Fairly easily done. Something like the following is all you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct state
{
    vector<vector<int>> p{3,vector<int>(3)};
};

int main(void)
{
    state *puzzle = new (state);

    for (auto& i : puzzle->p)    /* fill vectors */
        for (auto& j : i)
            cin >> j;

    for (auto& i : puzzle->p) {  /* display values */
        for (auto& j : i)
            cout << " " << j;
        cout  << '\n';
    }
}
```

However, the `<vector>` type provides auto memory management to begin with, so there is no need to declare the pointer in the first place. `<vector>` provides a smart pointer to handle deallocation when the instance goes out of scope. So unless you have a requirement that mandates pointer use, just declare an instance of `stat` as puzzle instead, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct state
{
    vector<vector<int>> p{3,vector<int>(3)};
};

int main(void)
{
    state puzzle;

    for (auto& i : puzzle.p)    /* fill vectors */
        for (auto& j : i)
            cin >> j;

    for (auto& i : puzzle.p) {  /* display values */
        for (auto& j : i)
            cout << " " << j;
        cout  << '\n';
    }
}
```

Regardless which method you choose, both provide the exact same output (which currently relies on you attempting no more values that originally requested, unless you use the `vector` member function to add to the existing instance, such as using the `push_back()` member, etc..

Both with provide identical output, e,g.

*Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/2dvals.txt
7 5 16
2 4 6
3 8 9
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vect2dinit_cin <dat/2dvals.txt
 7 5 16
 2 4 6
 3 8 9
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thaaaank you soooo much !!! This is exactly what I have been looking for !!
I really appreciate your help!! Thank you :D :D !!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I knew it must be some little part of the process. Good luck with your coding `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can can simply create a default constructor, and use the [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize the vector:

```
#include <vector>
struct state
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > p;
    state() : p(3,std::vector<int>(3)) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! Although I dont get any errors now...However to accept values ,is the following correct :   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { for(int j=0; j<3; j++) { cin >> puzzle->p[i][j] } } ?? 
Because it wont work. It just stops working...Sorry if all this sounds silly but I am clueless as to why it wont work :(

Comment: That is a different question, which is outside the scope of how to initialize the vector.  The vector in the answer given is already initialized, and now you're trying to use it.  Please open a different question concerning your usage *after* the vector has been initialized.

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you for your help !